# Adding google analytics data it Zoho CRM leads information

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, crm, zoho

I want Google Analytics data in my Zoho CRM leads information.

like below fields in my Zoho CRM are the fields which should be filled by Google Analytics.

[image]

although, I have tried a third party extension i.e. [GA Connector](https://gaconnector.com/) and it does work, but sometimes data is invalid or wrongly filled. So i tried to work on it myself by starting to study Google Analytics API, but I couldn't find a proper way to get a current users info which is right now on my website and submitting a form and I have to send his GA's data like his source/medium/campaign etc.

Now I am trying to do like when user is submitting any form on my website I am sending his info to GA and then after couple of minutes when data is reflected into GA dashboard then I am thinking to fetch that data of user's and update my ZOHO leads information, but I don't know what is the correct way to do that or how I am thinking whether right or wrong!

All I just want Zoho Leads info must contain these information above in the picture. If anyone have done this or can help me through this, I'll be really grateful. By the way, I am not a native English speaker so really sorry for any mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When a user( Visitor) submits the form you are pushing data to google analytics and later getting that information on to Zoho CRM leads module right. Instead, you can make use of web-form which is available on the Zoho CRM setup section and can be integrated into the Lead module in Zoho CRM. Web-forms will provide you a code snippet include code on to your website where ever it is required.
Such that as soon as users submit form, data will be reflected on to lead module.

FYI please find the link: https://www.zoho.com/crm/web-forms.html?src=fe

Or else you can try with Zoho CRM rest API to push data when a user submits the form to Zoho CRM leads module

Please find the link : https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/overview.html

Kindly revert in case of any clarifications.

Comment: this is not the case, I have zoho web forms on my website, but the data I want to include that form is Google Analytics Data like cpc, term search, campaign name which is generated by Google Analytics.